# How to deploy a wep abb within my work network?

Tags: python, django

I created an API for the company i work however i would like people having access in the same company network, how can i achieve this? I currently modified the allowed host as follow:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost','192.168.6.7', '127.0.1.1', '161.19.109.123']
```

however only work in my computer under IP: 127.0.0.1:8000, any suggestions? FYI i do not have administrator privilege.

Comment: use `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` when you run web server and then it should use all network cards in your computer to listen for clients. IP `'127.0.0.1'` uses virtual card called `loopback` which doesn't listen for clients on real cards - it only listens for other clients/programs installed on your computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to work, now, do you have any idea how to keep the server running without me having the ide open?

Comment: run it normally in console like any other program or script - `python script.py`. In Linux you can eventually add `&` at the end to run it in background.

Comment: You can use a Raspberry Pi as server, I did this as a cheap solution. You can use an Ubuntu server image for Raspberry Pi and use this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

Try  this to access project in a lan server

```
python manage.py runserver your_ip:port.
```

For example

my system IP address is something like 192.168.12.135, when we run run django development server its runs at localhost:8000, i mean with the system IP address and with a port 8000 like 192.168.12.135:8000 right.

it'll be accessible if you're running through apache or any other webservers other than the development server.
I would advice you to host and use a local apache server rather than using development server. Doing so, you can foresee the issues you'll be facing when moving to production.

Comment: would you be able to guide me a bit on your response? are you in linkedin?

Comment: So, if i run it from a webserver, would still be accesible only with the indicated IP?  I havent done this for one specific IP sorry for all the bother

Comment: add your LAN IP address to ALLOWED_HOSTS in the settings.py along with localhost. it would look like,

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost","192.168.8.160"] And try this-  python manage.py runserver your_ip:port